Render page send data from mongodb to html it is not working
I am getting the data from mongodbd with success; However, when I send to html page returns the error "workData is not defined". I am not using the app.js page to render.
I am using the '/api/time', router to render and save data to db. When I try to send the workData getting from mongoose in the r_time.js and render the data using res.render('pages/punch_log', {workData}), it returns the error "workData is not defined". How should I render this data?
app.js
//import base routes
const baseRoutes = require('./routes/base_routes')
const { time } = require('console')
app.use('/', baseRoutes)
app.use('/post', baseRoutes)
app.use('/punch_log', baseRoutes)
app.use('/login', baseRoutes)
app.use('/punch', baseRoutes)

//Set the view Engine EJS
app.set('views','./views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
//parse json bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:true}))
app.use('/api/time', timeRouter)

punch_log.ejs
  <main class="container">
            <h1>History Log</h1>
            <% workData.forEach(employee => { %>
            <div class="log">
                <p class="day" id="l-day"><%= employee.weekDay%> : <%= employee.day%></p>
                <p class="clock-in" id="l-clock-in">Clock In: 8:00</p>
                <p class="break-start" id="l-break-start">Break Start: 12:00</p>
                <p class="break-end" id="l-break-end">Break End: 13:00</p>
                <p class="clock-out" id="l-clock-out">Clock Out: 17:00</p>
                <p class="total-day" id="l-total-day">Total day: 7:00</p>
                <hr>
            </div>
           <% }) %>

punch_log.js
async function getIdFromEmployee(){
    console.log("function getIdFromEmployee", employeeId)
    const options = {
        method: 'get',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ employeeId })
    }
    try{
        const response = await fetch('/api/time/punch_log', options)
        if(!response.ok){
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`)
        }
    }catch(error){
        console.error("Network error:", error.message);
    }
}

//window.onload = getIdFromEmployee
window.onload = function(){
    if(window.location.href.indexOf('/punch_log') > -1){
        getIdFromEmployee()
    }
}

r_time.js
//history log send data
router.get('/punch_log', async (req, res) => {
    const {employeeId} = req.body
    console.log("entered: ", employee)
   /* Punch.find({employeeId: employeeId}).then(employee => {
        console.log("fetch punch_log history worked: ", employee)
        res.render('pages/punch_log', {employee})
    })*/
    try{
        let name = ''
        let workData = await Punch.find({employeeId: employeeId})
        console.log('work data result: ', {workData})
        res.render('pages/punch_log', {workData})
    }catch(error){
        console.error("send work date error: ", error)
    }
})

